# Apache Ignite Query on Near Cache does not give performance benefit over distributed Cache

Tags: ignite

I am doing performance test on **Ignite Cache** , I have created distributed cache with **10M** entries in a 3 node cluster, for this cache I have created a near cache with max capacity **10M**(entire cache with no eviction) in my client , when I compare the performance, I see significant difference in direct key based lookup ,below are the numbers with direct key lookup,

**Number of lookups**--100000   **Distributed Cache**--79447ms    **Near Cache**--29521ms

However when I fire a query on the cache (with only indexed fields in the query) , I don't get any performance advantage with near cache, does this mean that near cache does not replicate the indexes locally?, Below are the numbers for query based lookup

**Number of lookups**--100000   **Distributed Cache**--97516ms    **Near Cache**--99583ms

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Near cache makes sense only for key-value access where you can fetch individual entry to the client node and evict rarely accessed entries when needed.

When using SQL queries, Ignite doesn't know the set of required keys in advance, therefore it has to execute the distributed query anyway. Near cache is not involved in this case.